# How to use non-Nexus 5 emulators with Google Play Services dependency for my Google Maps app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, google-play-services

My testing approach involves using many emulators of various configurations (makes/models/dimensions/apis/targets).

I have recently upgraded to Android Studio 3.1.

My app is going on 3 years now and uses Google Maps v2 and I'd like to keep maintaining it (Google laughs).

Every emulator (other than the Nexus 5) I have now does not work because it says the Google Play Services needs to be updated and there appears to be no path to resolving it.  The Nexus 5 emulators don't have the error but display a blank map background.

When I attempt to remove any dependency on Google Play Services it ends up being a slippery slope (mainly replacing the fused location service).

**Question**: If I have a Google Play Services dependency (my first mistake perhaps?) in my Google Maps v2 app am I limited to the Nexus 5 emulators (which seem to have its own issues)?  If not then how to upgrade the other fine emulators (Pixel, other Nexus, Galaxy...)?

I see other questions out there and I'll continue staring at them but I'd like to understand what is a workable path for future maintenance - removing dependencies, upgrading something...

For reference:

The non-Nexus 5 relevant error is:

> (app) won't run unless you update Google Play services
>
> (A big fat
>   'Update' button is also displayed which throws an exception -
>   presumably because it is not installed on the emulator.)

The Nexus 5 relevant error is:

> E/Google Maps Android API: Google Maps Android API v2 only supports
>   devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above
>
> (Which I can't enable in the AVD manager for Nexus 5 emulators.)

Here's some typical gradle madness - I was trying to bump play-services down to 11.8.0 and this unfortunate magic happens (from gradlew app:depencencies):

> +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0 -> 12.0.1 |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1 |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1 |    |    |
>   +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 (*) |    |    |    --- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-license:12.0.1 |    |
>
>   +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:12.0.1 |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1 (*) |    |    |    --- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:12.0.1 | 
>   |    --- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-license:12.0.1 |
>   +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1 (*) |    --- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps-license:12.0.1

**Celebration**

@xiaomi correctly attributed the problem to play-services (or specifically play-services-maps) 12.0.1 so after some gradle battles I bumped all play-* down to 11.8.0 and the non-Nexus emulators work.

Lessons Learned:

- **Never blindly follow the gradle warning-advice to upgrade versions!**
- "gradlew app:dependencies" is your friend.

**Epilogue**

Think many times before following this:

[image]

Comment: Which version of Maps are you using ? if it is the 12.0.0, the emulator may not be ready to support it yet (play services too old). Try with a version 11.+ may solve your issue.

Comment: That was another slippery slope - I'm at 12.0.1 so let me bump it down and see how I got to that point.

Comment: Same results for both - I recall some gradle-madness that led me to 12.0.1 - but it's now at 11.+ and still not working.  Thanks though.

Comment: Interesting - I ran gradle dependencies and something is pulling in 12.0.1 play services - so I'll look at that.

Comment: @xiaomi - ok I resolved my gradle issues so I know for certain I'm using 11.8.0 and the non-Nexus 5 emulators now work!.  The nexus 5 still shows the blank map background but that's a different problem I suspect.  Feel free to post as answer.  A sub-project was pulling 12.0.1 still so I corrected that.

Comment: Good luck with your app :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is often a delay between the latest Google Play Service we can use and the one that the latest emulator can handle.

A solution, when the app on the emulator is asking for an update, is to use a lower version of Google Play Service.

If the map appears as blank, it is usually a problem with the [key registration](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)